# IBM Cloud Code Engine: How to pass non-JSON data in ping subscription?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I am trying to pass some form data to my app from a [Code Engine ping subscription](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-subscribing-events#eventing-ping-existing-app). In the create command, I have tried different methods to pass the data as part of the POST request, but it resulted in wrong parameters at runtime when the ping event fired.

```
  ibmcloud ce sub ping create -n tweety --destination twitterbot --path /tweet
      --schedule '07 4,8,13,17 * * *' --data 'SECRET_KEY=SET_YOUR_SECRET'
```

```
  ibmcloud ce sub ping create -n tweety --destination twitterbot --path /tweet
      --schedule '07 4,8,13,17 * * *' --data '{"SECRET_KEY":"SET_YOUR_SECRET"}'
```

How can I pass the data as regular text data, not as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a while to figure it out. [The CLI command allows to pass `--content-type`](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-cli#cli-subscription-ping). In the documentation is the example **application/json**. For regular data, it would be form data and urlencoded. The following works, i.e., using **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**:

```
 ibmcloud ce sub ping create -n tweety --destination twitterbot --path /tweet
     --schedule '07 4,8,13,17 * * *' --data 'SECRET_KEY=SET_YOUR_SECRET' 
     --content-type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 0):

The CLI does support non-json now:

ibmcloud ce sub ping create -n pinger --data "hello" -d myapp

will results in this for the body:

hello

Comment: I need to send a key / value pair, not just a value. Just sending it like shown above does not result in the correct form-type data.

Comment: You can put anything you want in that string and it should pass it along, untouched. So if you want it to look like JSON then make it JSON. Granted, as you mentioned earlier, if you want to set the content-type header then you'll also need to use the --content-type option, but w.r.t. the body you should be able to make it look like whatever you want. Including binary via the --data-base64 option.